# Insert variable number of rows into dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

I would like some assistance on how to insert empty rows into a dataframe. The number to insert will vary depending on the data present in two other columns. For example, I would like to fill in rows that represent sites, which did not get sampled for a particular date. Each site has 10 replicates. Suppose that I have days in which only 1 out of 8 sites sampled, so missing 70 rows (7 sites x 10 replicates) out of 80. On other days, I have only one missing replication within a site, so I have 79 complete cases. Then, I will need to fill in the empty rows with the site and replicate information, leaving only the cells in the value column empty.

The ideal output is to make a balanced dataframe as if there are no missing data at the replicate or site level. I am doing this to show my analysis to a colleague, who uses SAS.  Thanks much for showing me the power of R to a non R user!

Comment: Take a look at `merge()` and `rbind()`.

Comment: We prefer reproducible examples over paragraphs about data

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make up an example since the description isn't great.

```
`%ni%`<-Negate(`%in%`)

sites<-seq(1,10) #say you have 10 sites
df<-data.frame(site=seq(1,9),a=rep(2,9),row.names=NULL) #on a particular day you only see 9 of them

for(i in sites){ #checking to see if all sites are represented

    if(i %ni% df$site){
        print('not in')
        df[nrow(df)+1,'site']<-i #going to insert the missing site # with missing rows

    }

}
```